# How to get member list with telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I create a telegram bot. How to get member list with telegram bot?
What url should I use to get information about all members in channel?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33844290/382982) question and its answers. You cannot get a list of chat members from the Telegram Bot API, you'll need to use the standard Telegram API.

Comment: I want to find a method in API. and I don't use python

Comment: @mystdeim There have no method can do that

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this isn't possible at this time. In order to get user list, you need to use telegram API.

Comment: Telegram bot uses the API. OP is asking how.

Comment: Telegram has two kind of APIs. bot API and Telegram API. with bot API you cant have users list. but with its telegram own API you can have it all.  https://core.telegram.org/